# Programming an "add bookmark" button

Tags: joomla, bookmarks

I'm attempting to create a Joomla social bookmarking site as an experiment and I'm wondering how I might program a draggable bookmarklet that users can add to their bookmarks bar, similar to delicious.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources, smashing magazine is a great resource:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/

But here are some others you might try:

- http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/
- http://daringfireball.net/2007/03/javascript_bookmarklet_builder
- http://karmatics.com/aardvark/bookmarklet.html

It's not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a bookmarklet is just a chunk of javascript. Once you have that in place, anything you can do with javascript, you can do in your bookmarklet. This includes things like grab the current URL from the browser and send it (via ajax) to somewhere else.

That is pretty much the model you are looking at, with or without some additional javascript-driven UI for people to interact with when they create the bookmark,